# How to show a editable table with IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following situation (Asp.Net MVC 5):

In my ViewModel I have something like this

```
public partial class PersonViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int ActivityID {get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Activity> Activities {get; set; }
}
```

The controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit()
{
    var model = db.Person.Where(q => q.Status == 0).ToList();
    return View(model);
}
```

The (Razor) View

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.PersonViewModel>

<!-- some html code here -->

@{
    int i = 0;
    foreach(var item in Model)
    {
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(item => item.FirstName, new {@class = "form-control"})</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="PersonViewModel[@i].LastName" class="form-control" /></td>
        i++;
    }
}

<!-- some html code here -->
```

In the above view the TextBoxFor is not generated. So I've tried it with a for loop like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.[i].FirstName, new { @class="form-control" })
}
```

But in this scenario, it is not possible to select the FirstName property. Also when doing:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model[i].FirstName, new {@class="form-control"})
```

the property FirstName cannot be found. What am I doing wrong / do I not understand?

Comment: You returning a single `PersonViewModel` to the view, so it cant be `@model IEnumerable<Models.PersonViewModel>` - its `@model Models.PersonViewModel`

Comment: Make it `@model IList<Models.PersonViewModel>` so you can use a `for` loop (and its `model[i].FirstName`, not `model.[i].FirstName`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for pointing that out. I wrote down the wrong Action, I've changed the question (Action) so that it is returning a list.

Comment: @StephenMuecke That did the trick! I had to change IEnumerable to IList Now it is working!